# TypeORM: Implementing "WHERE NOT EXISTS" clause in querybuilder

Tags: typescript, typeorm, node.js-typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

In TypeORM, I am trying to create a query builder to generate the following Postgres query:

```
SELECT "mt"."id" AS "id"
FROM "main_table" "mt"
WHERE "mt"."some_value" = $1
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
             FROM "other_table" "ot"
             WHERE "ot"."some_other_value" != $2
               AND "ot"."join_id" = "mt"."join_id")
```

I see that since [this PR](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/pull/9303/files) from TypeORM, that we are able to add in .whereExists() on queryBuilders. However, I do not see a way to have the negation of this. Below is a code snippit of how the EXISTS should work

```
...
createQueryBuilder("main_table", 'mt')
    .where("mt.some_value = :some_value", { some_value: 4 })
    .andWhereExists(this.entityManager.createQueryBuilder()
          .from(AnotherTable, 'at')
          .where('ot.some_other_value != :val', {
            val: 5,
          })
          .andWhere('mt.join_id = ot.join_id') }
```

However, I don't see how one can use this with NOT (or even the NotBrackets, since that returns a whereFactory and doesn't have access to these exists methods).

Is my only hope going to a raw query?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

I had a similar issue and this worked for me.

```
   const someValues = await dataSource
        .createQueryBuilder('main_table', 'mt')
        .where("mt.some_value = :some_value", { some_value: 4 })
        .leftJoin('mt.other_table', 'other_table')
        .andWhere((qb) => {
            const query = qb
                .select()
                .where('other_table.some_other_value = :some_other_value', {
                    some_other_value : 5
                })
                .getQuery();
            return `NOT EXISTS(${query})`;
        })
        .getMany();
```

- We are basically taking an arrow function to get existing query builder with relations.
- We then add to this query builder the lookup we need and turn it into a string query with the `getQuery` method.
- We finally return the query wrapped in `NOT EXISTS`